# Method bounds() not invoked in custom QgsMarkerSymbolLayer

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

In a custom QgsMarkerSymbolLayer for drawing large symbol, the override method bounds() is never call. Other override methods are called : clone(), hasDataDefinedProperties(), startRender(), renderPoint(), stopRender() and usedAttributes().

Some lines of code of my plugin :

```
class MarkerSymbolLayerDebug( QgsMarkerSymbolLayer ) :
  def __init__( self, prop = None ) :
    QgsMarkerSymbolLayer.__init__( self )
...
  # for Debug : square of 10 pixel around the point
  def bounds( self, pt, qsrc ) :
    return QRectF( pt.x()-10, pt.y()-10, 20, 20 )
```

If I comment the bound() method, qgis doesn't complain but in [C++ include](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMarkerSymbolLayer.html#a0b146748dafdbd1e9159d82118865bec), the method is declared as pure virtual.

(Slackware 14.2, Python 3.7.2, qt 5.9.9, QGIS 3.12.1, sip-4.19.6)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from qgis team on [github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35377) : the method is It's currently used only during labeling.